# How to use string as object in redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

I've redux store which looks like below.

```
store = {
    a: {
        b: { value: "" }
    },
    c: { 
        d: { value: "" }
    }
};
```

From my component, I want to pass like below to minipulate `value` of `b`.

```
dispatch(doSomething({ value: 'my-value', place: "a.b" });
```

And, in my reducers, I want to handle like below.

```
doSomething: (state, action) => {
    const { value, place } = action.payload;
    state[place].value = value; // here, i want to refere -> state.a.b.value = value;
}
```

I don't want to handle like this:

```
doSomething: (state, action) => {
    const { value, place } = action.payload;

    if (place === 'a.b') state.a.b.value = value;
    else if (place === 'c.d') state.c.d.value = value;
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Reducer should return a new object. So `{ ...state, {...state[place], value}}`

Comment: sorry for confusion. just updated the question. @Rajesh

Comment: There are many variations of this question [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: Can you check this : https://jsfiddle.net/fc139sn8/ @Siri, let me know is this helpful or not

Comment: Thank you, all. I found an elegant solution provided by lodash `_.get` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get, from @AndyRay's comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is access/modify the object by string path. Maybe you can do something like this.

```js
let store = {
    a: {
        b: { value: "" }
    },
    c: {}
};

console.log(store)

function setNestedValue(obj, path, value) {
    let i;
    path = path.split('.');
    for (i=0;i<path.length-1;i++) obj = obj[path[i]];
    obj[path[i]] = value
}

setNestedValue(store,"a.b", "xx")

console.log(store)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const {value, place } = payload
let cur=state;
place.split(".").forEach((key, idx)=> {
 if(idx < place.length -1) {
cur[key] =value;
} else{
 cur=cur[key];
}
});
```

sent via mobile.. couldn't format much.. you can improvise this..